# Простейшая выборка из базы... Не все так просто

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, hibernate, select

Суть задачи: Выбрать из таблицы все записи, поле которых соответствует определенной регулярке. Применяя фильтр в самом ява коде Решил так:

```
CollectionUtils.filter(contacts, new Predicator(regExp));
```

Но, вычитать все записи из базы, как мне сказали не эффективно. Что же...

```
List contacts;
contacts = session.createCriteria(Contact.class)
          .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("name !~ ?",regExp, StringType.INSTANCE))
          .list();
```

Но, это как бы, нарушает первое условие (фильтр в коде). Вопрос как выбрать данные из базы соответствуя всем условиям?

Comment: А [tag:big-data] тут где?

Comment: @Nofate big-data, это как бы отягощающее условие здесь, подразумевается, что данных в таблице не один миллион. Но все же вы пожалуй правы big-data никак не повлияет на задание

Comment: Если совсем по хорошему то из условий задачи надо выкинуть регэксп, что-бы можно было эффективно выбрать только нужные данные не делай фулскан таблицы. Вплоть до изменения структуры БД. Фулскан это дорого, индексы это дёшево.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если данные нужно отфильтровать строго на Java, а выкачивать все данные в память неприемлимо, откройте курсор и вычитывайте данные из базы по мере обработки.

```
ScrollableResults itemCursor = createQuery("from Contact").scroll();`
```

Используется `itemCursor` как обычный итератор:

```
while (itemCursor.next()) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) itemCursor.get(0);
    // тут ваш код обработки объекта contact
}
```